# UIAlertController perform once after use UIAlertActionStyleDestructive button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uialertcontroller

in my app i have tableview and for clear all cells i given an action to clear button.
button work correctly and all cell deleted. but i want to give a option to user to canceled 
i used UIAlertController class and its work only one time after i chosen delete button.(its work every time if i chosen cancel button)

---

warning in console:

Warning:

Attempt to present UIAlertController on HistoryViewController which is already presenting UINavigationController

---

```
 - (IBAction)showNormalActionSheet:(id)event
{
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
                                      alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                      message:nil
                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel action")
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                               {
                                   NSLog(@"Cancel action");
                               }];

UIAlertAction *resetAction = [UIAlertAction
                              actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Clear all recent", @"Reset action")
                              style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive
                              handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                              {
                                  [self onDeleteClick];

                                  NSLog(@"Reset action");
                              }];

[alertController addAction:resetAction];
[alertController addAction:cancelAction];

[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];


}


//- (IBAction)onDeleteClick:(id) event {

- (void)onDeleteClick {
    linphone_core_clear_call_logs([LinphoneManager getLc]);
    [tableController loadData];
    editButton.hidden = ([tableView.dataSource tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] == 0);
    if(editButton.selected) {
        [editButton toggle];
        [self onEditClick:nil];
    }
}
```

[image: clear button]

Comment: Could not get what you want exactly from the question description, did you mean you need a mechanism to revert the delete operation when user hits cancel?

Comment: No.i want clear button work  exactly after i touch delete button. UIAlertController Not work very well after i delete all cell.

Comment: i solved by myself.for any body see this later I'm used               '[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil]; '               instead '[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];'